# Oneboxing comment links extracted from pages opened via Facebook doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

I've opened a question using a facebook link:

```
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/298117/why-are-the-sizes-of-programs-so-large?utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=se-facebook
```

I wanted to link one of the comments to chat, so I've copied it:

```
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/298117/why-are-the-sizes-of-programs-so-large?utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=se-facebook#comment618789_298117
```

However, it refused to show just the comment properly; instead the whole question was oneboxed.

Is this by-design with regard to facebook-based links, or is it indeed a bug?

[Here's a link to sandbox, showcasing the issue](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26039279#26039279).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in chat build 309. (Sadly, our chat system doesn't display its active build, so it's hard to tell when you'll see the change.)

Our existing comment detector only supports alphanumeric characters, underscore, ampersand, and equal signs in the query string. I've now extended it to allow dots and hyphens in the query string too, since that's what your URL from Facebook contains.

Comment: Thanks! I hope it doesn't open it for some malicious link play though :)

Comment: "hard to tell" - but please, do tell how to see that build number? :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard You can't. In order for the build number to be visible, two things must happen at our end: 1. we must set up our build system to "stamp" the assembly version with the build number, and 2. we must have code to read the assembly version and display it. In the case of Chat, neither of those pieces are in place.

Comment: Oh no. "hard to tell" sounded like a good challenge, but looks like it's more of Mission Impossible. Looking forward to see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267550/can-the-build-numbers-be-added-to-chat) implemented then, at some point in the future! :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's implemented now, but you knew that already. :-P

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young lol, very true and thanks again! :)