# Can the 'site design / logo © 2015 stack exchange, inc' in the footer of Chat be properly capitalized?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, copyright, footer

As [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261657/260841) shows, all sites were recently updated to have the correct capitalization of Stack Exchange Inc in the copyright part.

From:

> site design / logo © 2015 stack exchange, inc

To:

> site design / logo © 2015 Stack Exchange Inc

But this hasn't happened on Chat! Can it please be made to be consistent with all the other sites? To look like...:

> [image]

Comment: Area 51 is already done: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263765/13. It just needs to be deployed, and there's nothing really pressing for an A51 deploy at this stage.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young ok, removed that. Any plans/thoughts on the chat number though?

Comment: Related comment from Chris: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267182/oneboxing-comment-links-extracted-from-pages-opened-via-facebook-doesnt-work/267554?noredirect=1#comment867750_267554

Comment: Hmmm. As described in the blog post [We're Changing Our Name (Back) to Stack Overflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/), the new name of the Stack Exchange Inc. company is "Stack Overflow". Now I'm confused. The company name is "Stack Overflow" but the copywrite should be "Stack Exchange Inc"?

Comment: @DavidPostill no, the legal name is not changing. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266880/moderator-agreement-still-refers-to-stack-exchange-inc) comments by SE employee.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for the clarification ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is implemented and will appear in chat build 310.